# I am trying to create an eke cluster on Google console using jenkins pipeline .. bt the pipeline is throwing error and when I checked the error is

Tags: jenkins

{
"error": {
"code": 401,
"message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.%22),
"errors": [
{
"message": "Login Required.",
"domain": "global",
"reason": "required",
"location": "Authorization",
"locationType": "header"
}
],
"status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
"details": [
{
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
"reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
"domain": "googleapis.com",
"metadatas": {
"method": "compute.v1.NetworksService.List",
"service": "compute.googleapis.com"
}
}
]
}
}

Comment: Quote: `Request is missing required authentication credential.`

Comment: how do I add that, I have done it in the jenkins server still showing same error

Comment: What have you done? Be more specific. Have you read the [link provided](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in)?